# Use jQuery to populate a set of objects of the same class in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I suspect I'm abusing jQuery horribly here, but I'm trying to find an elegant solution to load 9 similarly styled columns with different data (lists of documents for 3 different products, each with 3 document categories).  I have a jQuery function that generates the unordered list object based on input parameters and I can append the generated object to every instance of the column class as each instance loads like this:

```
<li class="detail-column">
        <h4><a href="cm/getting_started.html">Getting Started</a></h4>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           hp_col('cm','learn');
        </script>
</li>
<li class="detail-column">
        <h4><a href="cm/learning.html">Learning</a></h4>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           hp_col('cm','learn');
        </script>
</li>
```

With a script that defines the hp_col function to build the  element that goes in each of the columns.  The script is essentially:

```
<script>
  function hp_col(prod, cat)
    {
        var pages = <!-- big old array of pages -->
        var ObjUl = $('<ul></ul>');

        for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
        {
          var Objli = $('<li></li>');
          var Obja = $('<a></a>');
          var Objp = $('<p></p>');

<!-- lots of stuff removed to be concise -->

          Objli.addClass("detail-column-item");
          if (pages[i].navtitle) {
            Obja.text(pages[i].navtitle.replace("&nbsp;", " "));
          } else {
            Obja.text(pages[i].title.replace("&nbsp;", " "));
          }
          Objli.append(Obja);

          ObjUl.append(Objli);
        }
        $('.detail-column').last().append(ObjUl);
        //ObjUl.html();
    }
</script>
```

The problem with this method is that (I guess because it's loading the content as the page loads) the screen flickers briefly (only in Chrome, not Firefox) during the load.  I'd rather use a DOMReady function to avoid this, but I can't figure out how to sequentially address each of the columns in the DOM.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could instead wrap those calls in the document.ready callback for jQuery so they run once the page is loaded.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Most likely happens when there is no items, then there are items.  Sounds like you need to do something more along the lines of templates on te client side like handlebars, hogan or mustache.

Comment: a little more cleaner approach can be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4CduD/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting weird timing because you have the calls to `hp_col()` interwoven inline with the parsing of the document which separates them in time and forces a repaint between them.  To allow all columns to be processed in one operation with one repaint, I'd suggest you change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".detail-column").each(function() {
        hp_col(this, 'cm', 'learn');
    }).find("ul").show();

});
```

And, change `hp_col()` to operate on the detail-column that was passed to it.

```
function hp_col(column, prod, cat)
{
    var pages = <!-- big old array of pages -->
    // ul objects are inserted into the DOM hidden
    // and all uls are then shown at the same time
    // after all inserted
    var ObjUl = $('<ul></ul>').hide();

    for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    {
      var Objli = $('<li></li>');
      var Obja = $('<a></a>');
      var Objp = $('<p></p>');

     // lots of stuff removed to be concise

      Objli.addClass("detail-column-item");
      if (pages[i].navtitle) {
        Obja.text(pages[i].navtitle.replace("&nbsp;", " "));
      } else {
        Obja.text(pages[i].title.replace("&nbsp;", " "));
      }
      Objli.append(Obja);

      ObjUl.append(Objli);
    }
    $(column).append(ObjUl);
}
```

To further protect against flicker, all `<ul>` items are inserted as hidden and then all are shown at once.

Simulation demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9MHfB/

---

Now, that you explain that the parameters to `hp_col)_` are different for each column, I can show you a relatively simple way to do that by adding the arguments as data elements for each column:

```
<li class="detail-column" data-prod="cm" data-cat="learn">
        <h4><a href="cm/getting_started.html">Getting Started</a></h4>
</li>
<li class="detail-column" data-prod="cm" data-cat="gs">
        <h4><a href="cm/learning.html">Learning</a></h4>
</li>
```

Then, modify the .each() loop to fetch those and pass them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".detail-column").each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        hp_col(this, item.data("prod"), item.data("cat"));
    }).find("ul").show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, the difficulty I have is that the parameters to the hp_col function need to be different for each call.  The first call would be hp_col(this, 'cm', 'gs') the next hp_col(this, 'cm', 'learn') and onwards, looping through 3 prods and 3 cats for each prod.

Comment: Perhaps I should just bite the bullet and give each of the columns an id.  Then I guess I could pass the id in as the column name to this function and it should work.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user3063510 - you didn't show that difference in your example, but that's easy to solve.  I've added that to my answer using data elements in each column.

Comment: @IanG - since it looks like you might be new to StackOverflow, do you know that when you get a helpful answer, you should select it as the "best answer" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will give both you and the person who helped you some reputation points here on StackOverflow.  Reputation points earn you privilieges on StackOverflow.  When you earn a few more reputation points yourself, you can also upvote any helpful answer on any question by clicking the up arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Done, and will make sure I do again in future.